# записать значения переменной в список

Tags: python, list, список

Есть ли какой-либо способ записывать значения переменной в список?
У меня есть переменная n, ей присваиваются разные значения, каждое на новой строке, до того момента пока не будет введен 0. После этого программа останавливается и далее выполняются некоторые действия с веденными данными.
Для этого мне нужен список всех введенных данных, поэтому хотелось бы узнать можно ли как то вводить значения переменной n в список и если такая возможность есть, то как?
В интернете не нашел, либо же плохо искал

```
n=int(input())
while n !=0:
   n=int(input())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = []
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        break
    arr.append(n)
```

либо так:

```
arr = [int(el) for el in iter(input, "0")]
```